# Upload to ifile.it through Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was wondering whether it's possible to upload a file from Mathematica to ifile.it. I have seen the [API](http://ifile.it/misc?article=api_upload_single) of ifile.it, however, I still don't know how it works. Furthermore, the closest example I've seen in Mathematica is '[Twittering with Mathematica](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/30/twittering-with-mathematica/)', but it's not clear to me, how can I use a GET request from that example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand the API description well, you'll need HTTP POST too. In Ragfield's Twitter blog you'll find a link to Twitter.m which contains a HTTPPost function. Perhaps you can use that one? I'll email Ragfield to bring your question under his attention.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks a lot. I look forward to know his answer. As for using Http Post request, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setup the Java HttpClient library.

```
<< JLink`

client = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"]
(*
Out[3]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject17955866594508801
*)
```

Determine which server to use.

```
method = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod", 
  "http://ifile.it/upload:api_fetch_upload_server"]

(*
Out[4]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject3301364646019073
*)

client@executeMethod[method]  

(*
Out[5]= 200
*)

id = "server_id" /. ImportString[method@getResponseBodyAsString[], "JSON"]

(*
Out[6]= "55"
*)
```

Upload the file to the server with a POST request using a MultipartRequestEntity with a FilePart.

```
method = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod", 
  "http://s" <> ToString[id] <> ".ifile.it/upload?apikey=" <> apikey]

(*
Out[7]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject25911718337052673
*)

filename = NotebookFileName[];

file = JavaNew["java.io.File", filename]

(*
Out[9]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject27844190972936193
*)

part = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart", 
  file@getName[], file]

(*
Out[10]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject17546309972000769
*)

part@setContentType["application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica"]

part@setName["Filedata"]

entity = JavaNew[
  "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity", 
{part}, method@getParams[]]

(*
Out[13]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject22100383232950273
*)

method@setRequestEntity[entity]

client@executeMethod[method]

(*
Out[15]= 200
*)

ImportString[method@getResponseBodyAsString[], "JSON"]

(*
Out[16]= {"file_key" -> "b8em0dc", 
 "file_md5" -> "acc9b7b3910b1e40188cf26ae3f20b80", 
 "file_mime" -> "text/plain", "file_name" -> "ifile.it.nb", 
 "file_size" -> "10473", "hash" -> "ca3d886713f64af6e9ffe6c3843d2eec", 
 "status" -> "ok", "url" -> "http://ifile.it/b8em0dc/ifile.it.nb"}
*)
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much. Now I will have to analyze your code to know how it works!

Comment: That was fast! A few questions: what modifications would be necessary to transmit binary files instead of a Mathematica notebook which is plain ASCII? Do you only change the content-type field or is an encoding to e.g. base64 using InputString or so necessary?

Comment: @sjoerd-c-de-vries This also works with binary files, no further encoding is necessary.  Just make sure to use the correct MIME type (e.g. image/jpeg).

Comment: Edited the code so it can be copied into Mma. Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

ragfield's answer gets points for not being a hack, but you can also do this without JLink:

```
UploadFile[url_, filePath_, urlParams___] := With[
  {
    bytes = Import[filePath, "Byte"],
    filename = StringJoin[FileBaseName[filePath], ".", FileExtension[filePath]]
  },
  URLExecute[
    url,
    urlParams,
    "Method" -> "POST",
    "MultipartElements" -> {
      {"file\"; filename=\"" <> filename, "application/octet-stream", bytes}
    },
    "Headers" -> {
      "Accept" -> "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Content-Type" -> "multipart/form-data"
    }
  ]
]
```

(Cross-answered from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52338/more-complete-mutipartdata-posts-using-urlfetch/97658#97658)