# Import from web - set user agent in Mathematica

Tags: browser, import, wolfram-mathematica, user-agent

when I connect to my site with Mathermatica (`Import["mysite","Data"]`) and look at my Apache log I see:
`99.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [22/May/2011:19:36:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6268 "-" "Mathematica/8.0.1.0.0 PM/1.3.1"`
Could I set it to be something like this (when I connects with real browser):
`99.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [22/May/2011:19:46:17 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 183 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.68 Safari/534.24"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica 9 has the new [URLFetch](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/URLFetch.html) function.  It has the option UserAgent.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know you can't change the user agent string in Mathematica. I once used a proxy server (CNTLM) to get Mathematica to talk with a firewall which used NTLM authentication (which Mathematica doesn't support).  CNTLM also allows you to set the user agent string.

You can find it at http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/. Basically, you set-up this proxy server to run on your own machine and set its port number and ip-address in the Mathematica network settings. The proxy adds user agent stuff and handles the NTLM authentication. Not sure how it works if you don't have a NTLM firewall. There are other free proxies around that might work for you.

**EDIT** The [Squid http proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/Download/) seems to do what you want. It has the `request_header_replace` configuration directive which allows you to change the contents of request headers.

Comment: +1 Using Ragfield's Jlink answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853134/upload-to-ifile-it-through-mathematica/5862918#5862918) I guess you could build up any request you want. Not using `Import[ ]`, AFAIK.

Comment: @belisarius
I have Squid proxy on my server, I'll try to set it up to change the useragent.
Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @enedene You're welcome. The proxy and the J/Link  (see WReach's answer) solutions should work. Pick the easier for you!

Comment: @enedene for Squid proxy you probably have to use the request_header_replace setting as in: `request_header_replace User-Agent Nutscrape/1.0 (CP/M; 8-bit)`

Comment: Yes, I've found it on squid help, unfortunately I'll have to compile it from source, as for to use request_header_replace I need to recompile squid with --enable-http-violations parameter. I'll probably try that for the weekends when no one is using squid at server.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a way to use the Apache HTTP client through JLink:

```
Needs["JLink`"]

ClearAll@urlString
urlString[userAgent_String, url_String] :=
  JavaBlock@Module[{http, get}
  , http = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"]
  ; http@getParams[]@setParameter["http.useragent", MakeJavaObject@userAgent]
  ; get = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod", url]
  ; http@executeMethod[get]
  ; get@getResponseBodyAsString[]
  ]
```

You can use this function as follows:

```
$userAgent =
  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.68 Safari/534.24";

urlString[$userAgent, "http://www.htttools.com:8080/"]
```

You can feed the result to `ImportString` if desired:

```
ImportString[urlString[$userAgent, "mysite"], "Data"]
```

A streaming approach would be possible using more elaborate code, but the string-based approach taken above is probably good enough unless the target web resource is very large.

I tried this code in Mathematica 7 and 8, and I expect that it works in v6 as well.  Beware that there is no guarantee that Mathematica will always include the Apache HTTP client in future releases.

**How It Works**

Despite being expressed in Mathematica, the solution is essentially implemented in Java.  Mathematica ships with a Java runtime environment built-in and the bridge between Mathematica and Java is a component called [JLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

As is typical of such cross-technology solutions, there is a fair amount of complexity even when there is not much code.  It is beyond the scope of this answer to discuss how the code works in detail, but a few items will be emphasized as suggestions for further reading.

The code uses the [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/).  This Java library was chosen because it ships as an unadvertised part of the standard Mathematica distribution -- and it also happens to be the one that `Import` appears to use internally.

The whole body of `urlString` is wrapped in `JavaBlock`.  This ensures that any Java objects that are created over the course of operation are properly released by co-ordinating the activities of the Java and Mathematica memory managers.

`JavaNew` is used to create the relevant Apache HTTP client objects, `HttpClient` and `GetMethod`.  Java expressions like `http.getParams()` are expressed in JLink as `http@getParams[]`.  The Java classes and methods are documented in the Apache HTTP client documentation.

The use of `MakeJavaObject` is somewhat unusual.  It is required in this case as a Mathematica string is being passed as an argument where a Java `Object` is expected.  If a Java `String` was expected, JLink would automatically create one.  But JLink is unable to make this inference when `Object` is expected, so `MakeJavaObject` is used to give JLink a hint.

**What about URLTools?**

Incidentally, the first thing I tried to answer this question was to use `` Utilities`URLTools`FetchURL ``.  It looked very promising since it takes an option called `"RequestHeaderFields"`.  Alas, this did not work because the present implementation of that function uses that option only for HTTP POST verbs -- not GET.  Perhaps some future version of Mathematica will support the option for GET.

Comment: Now this is a solution that is very easy to use.
Though, I'll need to search for help to understand how it works.

Comment: @enedene I added a "How It Works" section to give some pointers as to what you'll need to read up on.

Answer (score 6):

I'm extremely lazy and curl is more flexible in less code than J/Link, without the object management issues.  This is an example of posting data (userPass) to a url and retrieving the result in JSON format.

```
Import["!curl -A Mozilla/4.0 --data " <> userPass <> " " <> url, "JSON"]
```

I isolate this kind of thing in an impure function (unless it is pure) so I know it's tainted, but any web access is that way.

Because I use a pipe, MMA cannot deduce the type of file.  ref/Import mentions that « Import["!prog","format"] imports data from a pipe. » and « The format of a file is by default deduced from the file extension in its name, or by FileFormat from its contents. »  As a result, it is necessary to specify "CSV", "JSON", etc. as the format parameter.  You'll see some strange results otherwise.

> curl is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload of other useful tricks.

*From the [curl and libcurl welcome page](http://curl.haxx.se/).*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wikipedia has an article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUR. Also `man curl` has a lot of information (on anything but windows). Perhaps too much information in fact.

Comment: Good point.  I added the summary from the curl/libcurl page and linked.  Their words are better than mine. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica does all of its internet connectivity through a user specified proxy server. If, as Sjoerd suggested, setting one up is too much work, you might want to consider writing the call in C/C++, and then calling that from Mathematica. I don't doubt there are plenty of C libraries that do what you want in a few lines of code.

For calling C code within Mathematica, see the [C Language Interface documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html)

Comment: this is also good. First I'll try to find something for python, as I'm more comfortable with python than C.

Comment: Ok, for my purpose I see I can run external programs from mathematica, so I'll write a code in python, and then simply import the string that python will get as an output and use mathematica for the rest of it.

Thank you all, you've all supplied interesting solutions that will broaden set of possible implementations on my future problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use J/Link to make your web requests or call curl or wget on the command line.

Comment: Could you please post an example using J/Link to modify the useragent?