# Insert document into CouchDB using Mathematica

Tags: http, wolfram-mathematica, couchdb

I am looking for a way to insert a document into a CouchDB database using Mathematica.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038288/upload-images-to-imgur-from-mathematica) post, I tried it using the following code:

```
InsertDocument[key_, value_] := 
With[{url = 
  "http://couchdburl/database/"},
Import[url, "XML", "RequestMethod" -> "POST", 
 "RequestParameters" -> {"key" -> key, "value" -> value}]]
```

But when I try to execute it like this, for instance:

```
InsertDocument[110, 1]
```

I get the following error:

> Import::erropts: The value {key->110,value->1} specified for the option RequestParameters is invalid. >>

Edit:

Following kguler's comment, I converted the parameters to string, and the previous error disappeared.
I have also fixed the forgotten } in my code sample, and removed the concatenation of the url with the key parameter.
Now I'm experiencing a different error:

> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null,Utilities`URLTools`Private`URLTOOLSException[Utilities`URLTools`Private`BADCONNECTION,http://couchdburl/database/]] returned to top level. >>

I tried to make a request using curl to the couchDb url, using a dummy document:

```
curl -X POST http://couchdburl/database/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {}
```

and the response was as expected:

{"ok":true,"id":"57291ccea74c455beb2d7a37fe001624","rev":"1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"}

Am I still missing any option that should be used in the Import function?
Maybe some option to set the content-type as application/json?

Comment: Did you try making the passed arguments strings (`InsertDocument["100","1"]`) or making the last line in your code `"RequestParameters" -> {"key" -> ToString@key, "value" -> ToString@value}]]`? BTW, you are missing a right brace `}` in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it following the same idea as presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853134/upload-to-ifile-it-through-mathematica) SO question.

After some problems, the following code worked:

```
<< JLink`

client = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"];

method = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod", 
   "http://couchdburl/database/"];

method@setRequestHeader["Content-Type", "application/json"];

entity = 
 JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity", 
  "{\"key\":\"10\",\"value\":\"0\"}", "application/json", Null]

method@setRequestEntity[entity]

client@executeMethod[method]
```